# Store registration form data and multiple files in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, post

I have created a registration form and I want to store the data in MySQL when a user clicks on submit. But I'm getting the error in uploading the data to MySQL. I need multiple images and a file to and other data to be stored in the database after the user has filled all the details.

My created registration HTML form in which you can see all the details I'm trying to upload and you can help me with that.

**HTML FORM**

```
                    <form action="upload.php" method="post" id="regform">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter Your Full Address" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="perfoming" name="perfoming" placeholder="Performing Since" required />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <h3>Category</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="bollywood" value="Bollywood"> Bollywood DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="techno" value="Techno"> Techno DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="trap" value="Trap"> Trap DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="trance" value="Bollywood"> Trance DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="bigroom" value="Techno"> Big Room DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="hiphop" value="Trap"> Hip Hop DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="housemusic" value="Bollywood"> House Music DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="substep" value="Techno"> Dubstep DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="retro" value="Trap"> Retro DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="psytrance" value="Bollywood"> Psy-Trance DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="turntablist" value="Techno"> Turntablist DJ<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="other" value="Trap"> Any Other<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control" id="image" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control" id="image1" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image1" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control" id="image2" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image2" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control" id="attach_file" type="file" accept="image/*" name="attach_file" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="facebook" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook Url" required="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="twitter" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter Url" required="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="instagram" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram Url" required="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="about" name="about" placeholder="About Yourself" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #fff; color: #000; margin-top: 50px;">
                                    <input type="radio" name="platinum" value="amount"> Platinum 3000 <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gold" value="amount"> Gold 2000 <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="silver" value="amount"> Silver 1000 <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="button-control" form="regform" value="Submit">Proceed to Payment</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

My database connection file **connection.php**

```
       $servername = "localhost";  
       $username = "root";  
       $password = "";  
       $conn = mysqli_connect ($servername , $username , $password) or die("unable to connect to host");  
       $sql = mysqli_select_db ($conn,'test') or die("unable to connect to database"); 
?>
```

Finally my uploading file which throw which I'm trying to upload my data to MySQL.

**Upload.php**

```
<?php

require("connection.php");

$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' , 'pdf' , 'doc' , 'ppt'); // valid extensions
$path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory
if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['gender']) || !empty($_POST['mobile']) || || !empty($_POST['email']) !empty($_POST['address']) || !empty($_POST['performing']) || $_POST['bollywood'] || $_POST['techno'] || $_POST['trap'] || $_POST['trance'] || $_POST['bigroom'] || $_POST['hiphop'] || $_POST['housemusic'] || $_POST['substep'] || $_POST['retro'] || $_POST['psytrance'] || $_POST['turntablist'] || $_POST['other'] || !empty($_FILES['image']) || !empty($_FILES['image1']) || !empty($_FILES['image2']) || !empty($_FILES['attach_file']) || !empty($_POST['facebook']) || !empty($_POST['twitter']) || !empty($_POST['instagram']) || !empty($_POST['about']) || $_POST['platinum'] || $_POST['gold'] || $_POST['silver'])
{

$img1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$img2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$img3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$file = $_FILES['attach_file']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['attach_file']['tmp_name'];


// get uploaded file's extension
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$ext1 = strtolower(pathinfo($img2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$ext2 = strtolower(pathinfo($img3, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$ext3 = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// can upload same image using rand function
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img1;
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img2;
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img3;
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$file;

// check's valid format
if(in_array($ext, $ext1, $ext2, $ext3, $valid_extensions)) 
{ 
$path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
{
echo "<img src='$path' />";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender']; 
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$performing = $_POST['performing'];
$bollywood = $_POST['bollywood'];
$techno = $_POST['techno'];
$trap = $_POST['trap'];
$trance = $_POST['trance'];
$bigroom = $_POST['bigroom'];
$hiphop = $_POST['hiphop'];
$housemusic = $_POST['housemusic'];
$substep = $_POST['substep'];
$retro = $_POST['retro'];
$psytrance = $_POST['psytrance'];
$turntablist = $_POST['turntablist'];
$other = $_POST['other'];
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
$instagram = $_POST['instagram'];
$about = $_POST['about'];
$platinum = $_POST['platinum'];
$gold = $_POST['gold'];
$silver = $_POST['silver'];

//include database configuration file
include_once 'connection.php';
//insert form data in the database
$insert = $db->query("INSERT registration (name,gender,mobile,email,address,performing,performing,bollywood,techno,trap,trance,bigroom,hiphop,housemusic,substep,retro,psytrance,turntablist,other,facebook,twitter,instagram,about,platinum,gold,silver,image1,image2,image3,attach_file) VALUES ('".$name."','".$gender."','".$mobile."','".$email."','".$address."','".$performing."','".$bollywood."','".$techno."','".$trap."','".$trance."','".$bigroom."','".$hiphop."','".$housemusic."','".$substep."','".$retro."','".$psytrance."','".$turntablist."','".$other."','".$path."','".$path."','".$path."','".$path."','".$facebook."','".$twitter."','".$instagram."','".$about."','".$platinum."','".$gold."','".$silver."')");
//echo $insert?'ok':'err';
}
} 
else 
{
echo 'invalid';
}
}
?>
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

MySQL database and table:

```
CREATE TABLE `registration` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `performing` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `bollywood` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `techno` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `trap` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `trance` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `birroom` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `hiphop` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `housemusic` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `dubstep` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `retro` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `psytrance` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `turntablist` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `other` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `image1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `image2` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `image3` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `attach_file` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `facebook` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `twitter` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `instagram` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `about` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `platinum` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gold` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `silver` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm struck in this from last 2 days, tryin and changin code and searching on google but couldn't help myself.

Comment: What type of error you get.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) on line 8

Comment: Here is your error `!empty($_POST['mobile']) || || !empty($_POST['email'])` replace this with `!empty($_POST['mobile']) || !empty($_POST['email'])`

Comment: Your html form is a little confused - multiple duplicate IDs, element names that don't appear in the POST data checks, fields without names etc

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I agree with @RamRaider, this code is a real mess.

Comment: @RamRaider I have updated my code can you guys please check again. Thanks

Comment: @jay-blanchard I have removed mysql and used MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code was so flawed as to make it virtually unusable - incorrect HTML, sql injection vulnerabilities, poor database table structure and obviously errors which brought you to Stack in the first place.

I'd suggest that you alter your table structure like this:

```
create table `registration` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(25) not null,
    `gender` varchar(10) not null,
    `mobile` varchar(50) not null,
    `email` varchar(50) not null,
    `address` varchar(100) not null,
    `performing` varchar(20) not null,
    `bollywood` bit(1) null default null,
    `techno` bit(1) null default null,
    `trap` bit(1) null default null,
    `trance` bit(1) null default null,
    `bigroom` bit(1) null default null,
    `hiphop` bit(1) null default null,
    `housemusic` bit(1) null default null,
    `dubstep` bit(1) null default null,
    `retro` bit(1) null default null,
    `psytrance` bit(1) null default null,
    `turntabulist` bit(1) null default null,
    `other` bit(1) null default null,
    `image` varchar(128) not null,
    `image1` varchar(128) not null,
    `image2` varchar(128) not null,
    `attach_file` varchar(128) not null,
    `facebook` varchar(100) not null,
    `twitter` varchar(100) not null,
    `instagram` varchar(100) not null,
    `about` varchar(500) not null,
    `amount` varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (`id`)
)
collate='utf8_general_ci'
engine=innodb;
```

There are other refinements that one could, and probably should make, but for now this ought to suffice. Note the new column `amount` - this replaces the previous `silver`,`gold` and `platinum` - the HTML field element was a radio button yet the name of the element was actually what should have been the value ~ so in effect reversed name and value to make it function correctly.

Other changes are that various fields do not need to be `tinyint` when they only store either 1, 0 or null - hence opting for `BIT` as the field type. The column `id` has been assigned as a `primary key`.

Within the HTML and PHP code there are a few changes too in order to get this to work as I suspect it was intended.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );


    /* change this to include YOUR db connection or edit as appropriate */
    $dbhost =   '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );





    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        function uploaderror( $error ){ 
            switch( $error ) { 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                default: return "Unknown upload error";
            }
        }

        $status=null;
        $errors=[];

        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' , 'pdf' , 'doc' , 'ppt');




        /* Edit as appropriate */
        $path = 'c:/temp/fileuploads/stack/';   #   'uploads/'




        /* all mandatory fields */
        $required=array(
            'name'              =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'gender'            =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'mobile'            =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'email'             =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'address'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'performing'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'facebook'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
            'twitter'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
            'instagram'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
            'about'             =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'amount'            =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        /* Probably at least 1 is required */
        $optional=array(
            'bollywood'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'techno'            =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'trap'              =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'trance'            =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'bigroom'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'hiphop'            =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'housemusic'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'substep'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'retro'             =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'psytrance'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'turntabulist'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'other'             =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
        );

        /* all required */
        $filefields=array(
            'image',
            'image1',
            'image2',
            'attach_file'
        );

        /* Ensure that all the required fields are populated */
        foreach( array_keys( $required ) as $key ){
            try{
                if( !isset( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf( 'The field "%s" cannot be empty', $key ) );
            }catch( Exception $e ){
                $errors[]=$e->getMessage();
                continue;
            }
        }

        /* Ensure that all image fields are populated */
        foreach( $filefields as $field ){
            try{
                if( empty( $_FILES[ $field ] ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf( 'The file field "%s" is required', $field ) );
            }catch( Exception $e ){
                $errors[]=$e->getMessage();
                continue;
            }
        }




        if( empty( $errors ) ){

            $sql='insert into `registration`
                ( `name`,`gender`,`mobile`,`email`,`address`,`performing`,`bollywood`,`techno`,`trap`,`trance`,`bigroom`,`hiphop`,`housemusic`,`dubstep`,`retro`,`psytrance`,`turntabulist`,`other`,`facebook`,`twitter`,`instagram`,`about`,`amount`,`image`,`image1`,`image2`,`attach_file` )
                values
                ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )';

            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ) {
                /* Investigate errors and make corrections to db table &/or sql statement */
                exit( sprintf( 'Bad Foo! - %s', $db->error )  );
            }
            $stmt->bind_param(
                'ssssssiiiiiiiiiiiisssssssss',
                $name,
                $gender,
                $mobile,
                $email,
                $address,
                $performing,
                $bollywood,
                $techno,
                $trap,
                $trance,
                $bigroom,
                $hiphop,
                $housemusic,
                $dubstep,
                $retro,
                $psytrance,
                $turntabulist,
                $other,
                $facebook,
                $twitter,
                $instagram,
                $about,
                $amount,
                $image,
                $image1,
                $image2,
                $attach_file
            );



            $images=array();

            foreach( $filefields as $index => $field ){
                try{
                    /* assign a variable variable - cast as an object for convenience */
                    $obj=(object)$_FILES[ $field ];

                    if( isset( $obj ) ){

                        /* get details of the file */
                        $name=$obj->name;
                        $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
                        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
                        $size=$obj->size;
                        $error=$obj->error;

                        if( !in_array( $ext, $valid_extensions ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf('The file "%s" has an illegal file extension "%s"',$name,$ext ) );


                        if( $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){

                            /* create the final name for the file to be saved */
                            $saveas = sprintf( '%s/%d.%s', $path, mt_rand( 1000, 1000000 ), $name );
                            $bytes  = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $saveas );

                            if( $bytes ){
                                $images[ $field ]=(object)array(
                                    'name'  =>  $name,
                                    'size'  =>  $size
                                );                              
                            } else {
                                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'There was an error storing "%s"', $name ) );
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception( sprintf( 'There was a problem with "%s" - %s', $name, uploaderror( $error ) ) );
                        }
                    }
                }catch( Exception $e ){
                    $errors[]=$e->getMessage();
                    continue;
                }
            }




            $args=array_merge( $required, $optional );
            filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );



            foreach( $filefields as $field ){
                ${$field}=$images[ $field ]->name;
            }



            if( empty( $errors ) ){
                $status=$stmt->execute();
                if( $stmt->errno!= 0 ) exit( sprintf( 'Critical Error: [%d] - %s',$stmt->errno,$stmt->error) );
                $stmt->close();
            }



        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                if( !empty( $status ) ){

                    $message = $status ? 'success: record added' : 'failure: record was not added';
                    $colour  = $status ? 'green' : 'red';

                    printf('<span style="color:%s">%s</span>', $colour, $message );
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <div class='row' style='margin-top: 50px;'>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='name' name='name' placeholder='Enter name' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='gender' name='gender' placeholder='Gender' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='number' class='form-control' id='mobile' name='mobile' placeholder='Mobile Number' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='address' name='address' placeholder='Enter Your Full Address' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='performing' name='performing' placeholder='Performing Since' required />
                </div>

                <div class='col-md-6' style='margin-top: 20px;'>
                    <h3>Category</h3>
                </div>


                <div class='col-md-6'></div>


                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='bollywood' value='1'> Bollywood DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='techno' value='1'> Techno DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='trap' value='1'> Trap DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='trance' value='1'> Trance DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='bigroom' value='1'> Big Room DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='hiphop' value='1'> Hip Hop DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='housemusic' value='1'> House Music DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='dubstep' value='1'> dubstep dj<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='retro' value='1'> Retro DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='psytrance' value='1'> Psy-Trance DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='turntabulist' value='1'> Turntabulist DJ<br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4' style='margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='other' value='1'> Any Other<br>
                </div>


                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input class='form-control' type='file' accept='image/*' name='image' />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input class='form-control' type='file' accept='image/*' name='image1' />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input class='form-control' type='file' accept='image/*' name='image2' />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input class='form-control' type='file' accept='image/*' name='attach_file' />
                </div>


                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='url' class='form-control' id='facebook' name='facebook' placeholder='Facebook Url' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='url' class='form-control' id='twitter' name='twitter' placeholder='Twitter Url' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='url' class='form-control' id='instagram' name='instagram' placeholder='Instagram Url' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='about' name='about' placeholder='About Yourself' required />
                </div>


                <div class='col-md-12' style='background-color: #fff; color: #000; margin-top: 50px;'>
                        <input type='radio' name='amount' value='platinum'> Platinum 3000 <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='amount' value='gold'> Gold 2000 <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='amount' value='silver'> Silver 1000 <br>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <input type='submit' />
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                /* were there any errors? display them perhaps... */
                if( !empty( $errors ) ) printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $errors, true ) );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the brief description of my error and pointing out all the details and correcting me. I will keep all of it in mind and write code according to that from now on. The HTML and PHP weren't intended thought. Also, I would like to understand why you use colour in ```$required array```. This code still didn't work for me or not uploading data on the server. I read all your comments and did the necessary changes.

Comment: oops - I initially used `colour` rather than `amount` but must have forgotten to change when I posted this. The above worked fine for me in testing

Comment: It works, thank you. The confusion was with colour and amount.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate PayUmoney bolt gateway but after clicking on the submit it showing me blank page instead of the payment. Can you help me with this?

Comment: To be honest that sounds like it would be better suited to a new question

Comment: RamRaider What to do if I want to make those images optional?

Comment: I modified the above and created a pastebin - it will be active for 1 day only.

https://pastebin.com/R0UJGLaM